# How can I get the "keyboard input" in IBM Watson studio?

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

Now I am taking IBM Data Science Professional certificate' course.
And, I am using Jupyter Notebook on 'IBM Watson Studio'.
My question is this.

when I want to receive the keyboard input on Jupyter notebook, There is a problem like this.

[image]

I can't write any input to list 'a'.
I want to put some string to 'a' like `a=['h','e','l','l','o']`. But, I can't write any input to list 'a'.
So, list 'a' remains empty. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it should not be empty, if you provide `['h','e','l','l','o']` also, list will not do what you are intending to get. The output datatype of `input()` is `str`. `list("abc")` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I think you want `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: just to clarify, do you want to pass a list as an input to the input function? because if so you can achieve a similar result by formatting the input string and then using a list comprehension or for loop to populate the desired list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine, but you may have re-defined `input` somewhere in your code, or your notebook is bugged. Try the following:

```
x = input("Enter text: ")
a = list(x)
```

Comment: I don't know why, but some how It works well today!
I really appreciate your comment :D.